# ios 8.2 and above settings bundle is not showing selected item but Default

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8.3, ios8.2, settings-bundle

I am facing a issue with App settings, i am using settings bundle to select the environment, but once selected and going back to app settings its showing again the default one as selected.

This is observed only from ios 8.2 and above(Device and simulator).
My settings bundle plist looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>1</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>Environment</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Environment</string>
            <key>Titles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Live</string>
                <string>Stage</string>
            </array>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSRadioGroupSpecifier</string>
            <key>Values</key>
            <array>
                <string>0</string>
                <string>1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I already see some info in Stack overflow that this is existing bug from Apple, I hope if some one has any any update on it.

Comment: may be these could help you - 
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163955/ios-8-2-settings-bundle-default-value
2.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155410/ios-8-2-nsuserdefaults-standarduserdefaults-returning-nil?rq=1
3.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077431/register-default-settings-from-the-settings-bundle-plist-file?rq=1 4.http://www.codedisqus.com/0SNjqXVqee/ios-settingsbundle-localization-difficulties.html

Comment: I encountered the same thing but only when using a PSRadioGroupSpecifier, aka a Radio Group Element as Apple calls it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/RadioGroupElement.html

Since XCode's plist editor does not recognize this type, I think Apple did not really implement this completely. So I used a Multi Value Element (PSMultiValueSpecifier) instead, which is basically the same thing except with the values in a separate screen.

Answer (score 1):

If your apperance settings are set during launch, you must reload your app viewcontrollers to display the change, so you could add to your appDelegate something like:

`NSString *type` in your ivars

then

```
type = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefault] objectForKey:@"Your key"];
```

in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

and finally, in your `didEnterForeground` method, add

```
if(![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefault] objectForKey:@"Your key"] isEqualToString:type]){
  //Reload your main view controller
  [self.window.rootViewController viewDidLoad]; 
  [self.window.rootViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug in iOS 8 and up where Radio Button settings always revert to the default value in the settings app. Others are running into the same issue: [iOS settings bundle PSRadioGroupSpecifier does not show selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389422/ios-settings-bundle-psradiogroupspecifier-does-not-show-selected-value)