# iOS settings bundle PSRadioGroupSpecifier does not show selected value

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I implemented a PSRadioGroupSpecifier like so: [image: [settings bundle excerpt]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh9pa.png). Regardless of which value a user selects inside the radio button group, next time the settings are opened the default value is marked as selected. Imho this is a **bug in iOS**, as i figured out that the value of the settings property is correctly set and could be retrieved.

Question: How to come around the false display in settings app WITHOUT using `PSMultiValueSpecifier`?

Comment: Agreed this seems like a bug in the settings app, where it will always revert to the default value for radio groups. Having the same problem. Will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios 8.2 and above settings bundle is not showing selected item but Default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324452/ios-8-2-and-above-settings-bundle-is-not-showing-selected-item-but-default)

Comment: `PSMultiValueSpecifier` seems the way to go here. It renders differently, but it's not broken. Thanks for sharing this. `PSRadioGroupSpecifier` is broken in 8.2+